# Can't add Java Project nature to nested m2Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, m2eclipse, facet

I have a nested m2Eclipse project in Indigo. The parent project contains the src folder that is used by the nested modules (see structure below).

- parent

  - src
  - pom.xml
  - module1

    - pom.xml
  - module2

    - pom.xml

Running mvn package from the Maven run configurations builds all the modules, so dependency management appears to be working. However, I don't have a MAVEN DEPENDENCIES folder and I can't use Java content-assistance or any other Java Project capabilities on any of the source files. I tried converting the project to faceted form and adding the java facet, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

It is because the parent is not a java project but a pom project.

While developing a maven project SET in eclipse using m2e, you are supposed to import all the projects into your workspace and you should do java development in module1 & module2.

With the current way of editing java source files, you are in detached mode and none of the advanced instruments from JDT is available to you as this java file is not part of a known java model to eclipse.

Try right clicking on your project and do Import... -> Existing Maven Projects. This way you should end up with three projects in your workspace one being the pom project and other two (supposedly both) java projects. Then all java development should be done in project1 and project2. M2e is smart enough to create in-workspace dependencies for the java projects.

Hasan Ceylan

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, since the src folder is nested in the parent, I still can't use Java content assistance, and Eclipse won't allow me to link the src folder to the build path of any of the modules.

Comment: By maven convention, any pom project should not contain any java source. All java sources should be contained in the sub modules. 

If what you are trying to archive is to add module 1 and module as a dependency to parent project you should have 4 projects one being the pom project, the other being the main project and the latter two are the modules and the main project should include dependencies to module 1 & 2. Hope this clears it out.